# « Et », « puis » ou « virgule » dans « À maintes reprises son amoureux est revenu à la maison et/puis/, il sentait le fond de tonne. »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> C’est arrivé à maintes reprises que son amoureux est revenu à la maison tardivement puis il sentait le fond de tonne.

> C’est arrivé à maintes reprises que son amoureux est revenu à la maison tardivement et il sentait le fond de tonne.

> C’est arrivé à maintes reprises que son amoureux est revenu à la maison tardivement , sentant le fond de tonne.

Autre tournure qui me passe par la tête [merci LPH]:

> C’est arrivé à maintes reprises que son amoureux est revenu à la maison tardivement avec une odeur de fond de tonne.

C’est un propos qui serait tenu oralement, je cherche donc, dans un souci de simplicité langagier,  une tournure coulante qui respecte le bon usage.

Registre de langue attendu: courant

Vous pouvez repenser la phrase du tout au tout (pour autant qu’elle se dise plus aisément et qu’elle soit plus élégante) et me la faire connaître.

Comment: son amoureux fait vieux jeu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'abord La grammaire est incorrecte (temps) et ensuite « puis » ne convient pas du point de vue sémantique, ce qui est difficile à expliquer.

Pour rester dans la forme initiale de la phrase je la modifierais ainsi.

- C’est arrivé à maintes reprises que son amoureux **soit** revenu à la maison tardivement **et qu'il sente** le fond de tonne. (*parlé ou écrit*)
- C’est arrivé à maintes reprises que son amoureux **soit** revenu à la maison tardivement **sentant** le fond de tonne. (*écrit*)

Comment: Pourriez-vous expliquer pourquoi il faut recourir au subjonctif dans la phrase?

Comment: @Pogo La raison, telle que je la conçoit (je n'ai pas de référence sauf mon habitude de ces constructions) c'est qu'il existe un parallèle établi par « et que », et comme le subjonctif est le mode normal après « arriver que » il faut maintenir ce mode parce que cette seconde action (ou état) est considéré comme « étant sur le même plan ». Par exemple on écrit « Il est arrivé que je mette le feu à l'huile et que je sois forcé d'utiliser l'extincteur. », et si on y réfléchit bien, aucun autre mode ne semble convenir dans la seconde partie. (1/2)

Comment: @Pogo C'est comme si cette construction reposait sur l'ellipse de « c'est arrivé (en même temps) » après « et ».

Answer (score 0):

Je privilégie la simplicité et ce qui me semble le plus courant dans mon sociolecte (Montréal) mais avec une dose de familiarité, en ce sens que discuter de ça avec un tiers l'implique d'une certaine manière à mon avis :

> C'est souvent arrivé que son amoureux soit rentré tard à la maison et
> il sentait la tonne.

Je trouve « en sentant » bizarre, probablement à cause de l'homophonie qui créé une impression de trompe-l’œil. Avec *puis* je trouverais ça usuel de prononcer « pis ». Je pourrais prononcer le verbe être « soye » pour faire encore plus familier mais ce n'est pas ce qu'on recherche et la prononciation plus usuelle avec la phrase proposée constituent ma « voie du milieu »...

Comment: *Sentir le fond de tonne !* Ha ha ha :-)  J'ai découvert à l'occasion le lien entre la tonne (1000 kg) et le tonneau.